# Running a Python script that creates a webpage on a server

Tags: python, php, html, server, bottle

I have a Python script that creates a web page displaying some text at localhost port 8080. I have access to a server, and would the script to run there so that it is always running and available anywhere.

I am using the bottle, requests and json libraries.

This is the last line of code in the script that is executed to locally create a web page:

```
    run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

How would I change this to run on a server? I also have WinSCP and PuTTy to add the script to the public_html directory of the server and I can change permissions. Sorry, I am a novice in this subject.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on the `Apache httpd` configuration. But, assuming most defaults were left in place and `Apache httpd` serves `index.html`, you can just create your webpage (which you tested locally on port 8080) and overwrite that file. But, this only works well if you have a static page and no logic in your `Python` code. If you want to combine the power of `Apache httpd` and `Python` (have the former call the latter) you'll have to use [mod_wsgi](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/).

Seeing as you're novice in this subject, I suggest starting off with a simple `Apache httpd` server according to their [quickstart](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/getting-started.html). Then, once you have a few successful requsets under your belt, add `mod_wsgi`.